# How can I handle the most basic user auth in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've implemented really basic user authentication before - generate a session cookie when logging in, and when the user loads a page with authentication just check the cookie.

However, the complexity of Spring Security / Apache Shiro is really confusing me.

All I really want is:

- be able to have a user log in once and see their username on every page they visit (like on Stackoverflow)
- have this login persist for a reasonable length (cookie expiry time or something like that)

It looks like I have the option of using EhCache or implementing my own subclass of... something... to use something like postgres.

I seem to have gotten the first thing I want working in Apache Shiro:

```
    Subject sub = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
    token.setRememberMe(remember);
    try {
        sub.login(token);
        // ...
```

But I'm super stuck on how to get this session to persist between restarts of the spring webserver. Like, I know Stackoverflow highly recommends a code example but I literally don't even know where to start. Right now my "progress" on trying to **figure out how to persist sessions between restarts** (bolded to clarify what I'm asking) is literally the single line

```
    DefaultWebSecurityManager dwsm = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    // ...
    dwsm.setCacheManager(new EhCacheManager());
```

and I don't even know what that actually does.

I would really appreciate any kind of guidance here since I really don't even know where to begin and the documentation I've been able to find is unfortunately not super thorough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats one of the problems with just sessions. That they are not persistant over restarts unless you save your sessions.

Now days people usually use a token based approach like oauth2.

The flow in a token based authentication system is:

- User sends his/hers credentials to an authorizationserver (oauth2).
- If credentials were correct they get a token back
- The client (webpage) makes a request to the backend to get the user object and supplies the token in this call as an "Authorization"-header.
- The backend takes the token and sends it to the authorizationserver (oauth2) to check its validity.

  - if the token is valid the backend server fetches the user object and sends this to the client.
  - The client gets the username from the user object and stores this in its state (react, redux if such an app). In every call to the backend the client must supply the token it got from the first login so that the server always knows that the caller is whom he/she claims to be